# I’m looking to trigger specific actions within an app using the Apple Shortcuts app

Tags: ios, mobile

Quick back story, I’m looking to setup a physical Photobooth using the WifiBooth app and the Instax SHARE SP-3 printer. Unfortunately, there isn’t a way for WifiBooth and the SP-3 to talk to each other as the printer isn’t AirPrint enabled and will only work with the proprietary Instax SHARE app.

Basically I’d like to take my latest photo and have the Instax Share app automatically import it and send it off to the SP-3 to print.

I have tried IFTTT, but no luck - so I was wondering if there’s a way to do this using the Shortcuts app instead? As I’ve seen you can add in sort of do some basic programming in there.